# How to send events in Quarkus Command mode test

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to test a Quarkus app in command mode.
The app consumes some kafka events and aggregates some values before exiting.

In my test I have setup a kafka testcontainer where I can send some mocked events.

When I inject an emitter in my @QuarkusMainTest-test the emitters are not injected (as per documentation no injection is allowed.

Are there any ways around this? I tried to manually create a kafka producer, but I can't access the config for the kafka test container created by @QuarkusTestResource(KafkaTestResource.class).

My test looks something like this

```
@QuarkusMainTest
@QuarkusTestResource(KafkaTestResource.class)
class StatisticsTest {

    @Channel("TOPIC")
    Emitter<SomeClazz> emitter;

    @Test
    void shouldAggregateValues(QuarkusMainLauncher launcher) {
        emitter.send(new SomeClazz(10);
        emitter.send(new SomeClazz(5);

        LaunchResult result = launcher.launch();

        Assertions.assertEquals(0, result.exitCode());
        Assertions.assertTrue(result.getOutput().contains(15));
    }
```

Comment: So you are actually trying to send an event from the test?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to send an actual event from the test.
The KafkaTestResource starts a kafka test-container https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/